# How do I return all order items for all orders?

Tags: c#, linq

I had an interview question and could not complete it & was wondering the correct answer.

```
public interface ICustomer
{
    string Name { get; }
    IEnumerable<IOrder> Orders { get; }
}

public interface IOrder
{
    IEnumerable<IOrderItem> OrderItems { get; }
}

public interface IOrderItem
{
    IEnumerable<IProduct> Products { get; }
}

public interface IProduct
{
    string Name { get; }
}

public class CustomersController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<IOrderItem> List(ICustomer customer)
    {
        // Return All OrderItems for all orders
    }
}
```

Comment: [SelectMany](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany.aspx)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flatten an enumerable with `SelectMany`:

```
return customer.Orders.SelectMany(o => o.OrderItems);
```